# On $\varepsilon-$interpolating and $\varepsilon-$integral preserving functions

Tags: real-analysis, interpolation, approximation-theory, interpolation-theory

Let us consider a function $f \in \mathcal{C}^{2n+1}(\mathbb{R})$ and a fixed $\varepsilon$>0. We say that a function $\phi \in \mathcal{C}^{2n+1}(\mathbb{R})$ is an $\varepsilon-$interpolating function of $f$ if:
\begin{cases}
 \phi^{(k)}(0) &= f^{(k)}(0) + A_k \varepsilon^{2n+1-k},\quad k=0, \cdots, n-1,\\
 \phi^{(k)}(\varepsilon) &= f^{(k)}(\varepsilon)+B_k \varepsilon^{2n+1-k},\quad k=0, \cdots, n-1,
\end{cases}
where the constants $A_{k},B_{k}$ do not depend on $\varepsilon$.
In other words, $\phi$ approximates $f$ and its derivatives at the extremes of $[0,\varepsilon]$ with error proportional to some power of $\varepsilon$.
Besides that, we say that $\phi$ is $\varepsilon-$integral preserving to $f$ if
\begin{equation}
 \int_{0}^{\varepsilon} \phi(x) \,dx = \int_{0}^{\varepsilon} f(x) \,dx\\
\end{equation}

**Question**: If $\phi$ is an $\varepsilon-$interpolating function and $\varepsilon-$integral preserving to $f$, then how well $\phi(x)$
approximates $f(x)$ for $x \in ]0,\varepsilon[$? In particular, does exist a constant $C$ that do not depend on $\varepsilon$ such that:
\begin{equation}
|f(x)-\phi(x)| \leq C \varepsilon^{2n+1}
\end{equation}
I'm not sure if this is true, but my intuition says that this result may be true.
Besides that, if it is helpful, I am willing to assume that $\phi$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq 2n$.

**Attempt**:
For $x \in ]0, \varepsilon[$, I am considering the following Taylor's expansions:
\begin{align}
\phi(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\phi^{(k)}(0)\frac{x^k}{k!} +  \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\phi^{(k)}(0)\frac{x^{2n+1}}{k!}+ \phi^{(2n+1)}(\alpha)\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f^{(k)}(0)\frac{x^k}{k!} +  \sum_{k=n}^{2n}f^{(k)}(0)\frac{x^{2n+1}}{k!} + f^{(2n+1)}(\beta)\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
\end{align}
Subtracting these equations, we get
\begin{align}
f(x) -\phi(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\big(f^{(k)}(0)-\phi^{(k)}(0)\big)\frac{x^k}{k!} +  \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\big(f^{(k)}(0)-\phi^{(k)}(0)\big)\frac{x^k}{k!}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{A_k \frac{x^k}{k!} \varepsilon^{2n+1-k}} \quad +\quad \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\big(f^{(k)}(0)-\phi^{(k)}(0)\big)\frac{x^k}{k!} +  \bigg(f^{(2n+1)}(\beta)-\phi^{(2n+1)}(\alpha)\bigg)\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
\end{align}
Therefore:
\begin{align}
|f(x) -\phi(x)| &\leq  
\varepsilon^{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{|A_k|}{k!} + \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\big|f^{(k)}(0)-\phi^{(k)}(0)\big|\frac{\varepsilon^k}{k!}  \\ &+\bigg|f^{(2n+1)}(\beta)-\phi^{(2n+1)}(\alpha)\bigg|\frac{\varepsilon^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
\end{align}

It remains to bound the term $\big|f^{(k)}(0)-\phi^{(k)}(0)\big|$ for $k=n, \cdots, 2n$. If we prove that
\begin{equation}
\big|f^{(k)}(0)-\phi^{(k)}(0)\big|  \leq A_k \varepsilon^{2n+1-k} \quad \text{for} \quad k=n, \cdots, 2n
\end{equation}
for constants $A_k$ that do not depend on $\varepsilon$, then we are done.

So far, I have not used the information $\phi^{(k)}(\varepsilon) = f^{(k)}(\varepsilon)+B_k \varepsilon^{2n+1-k}\quad$ for $k=0, \cdots, n-1$ and I do not see how this helps to bound $\big|f^{(k)}(0)-\phi^{(k)}(0)\big|\quad$ for $\quad k=n, \cdots, 2n$.

I do appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the factorials are missing in your attempt

Comment: @fwd thanks for pointing this out. I edited my question.

Comment: Why don't you try Taylor expanding only up to $(n-1)$-st order?

Comment: If I expand up to $(n-1)-$st order, I would get $|f(x)-\phi(x)| \leq C \varepsilon^{n+1}$, but this is not the desired power of $\varepsilon$